# I cannot get .effect to work in my jQuery function

Tags: jquery, effects

Hi I am currently doing a project that requires me to sort and filter products on a page using jQuery. I have my script working perfectly showing and hiding results based on the user selection however I want the animations between transitions to run differently. I have them set already using fadeOut and fadeIn. But was wanting to make use of the .effects feature of jQuery. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or if I can even use it. See my code below.  Heres my full script using fade.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('ul#filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('ul#selection li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {

        $('ul#selection li').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow').addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

});

Below is my attempt at using the effect with fold.

```
 $('ul#selection li').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
            $(this).effect('fold','slow').addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or any indication that points to where the problem resides?

Comment: [Effect()](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) is part of jQuery UI. Are you including that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you are including jQuery UI
2. Try this: `$(this).effect('fold','slow', function(e) { $(this).addClass('hidden'); })`

If you just chain `.addClass()` directly after the `.effect()`, it will happen immediately, rather than when the effect is complete. Therefore, if your `.hidden` class actually hides things with CSS, they will seem to disappear right away, before you notice the fold effect. So `.addClass()` should be a callback to `.effect()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Stupidly I hadn't included the jQuery UI